# Check if a number is odd in c++. Strange behaviour of code

Tags: c++, compilation

I am a teaching assistant for computer science and one of my students submitted the following code to check whether an integer is odd or even:

```
int is_odd (int i) {
    if((i % 2 == 1) && (i % 2 == -1));
    else;
}
```

Surprisingly (at least for me) this code gives correct results. I tested numbers up to 100000000, and I honestly cannot explain why this code is behaving as it does.

We are using gcc v6.2.1 and c++

I know that this is not a typical question for so, but I hope to find some help.

Comment: Gives correct results? The function is supposed to return an int, but returns nothing. Its behavior is undefined. How did you determine the results are "correct"?

Comment: When you actually fix it, it isn't correct at all. http://ideone.com/5bs2aF

Comment: The behaviour is undefined. Look [here](http://melpon.org/wandbox/permlink/HbRsBuRh5fAnBA0U). One could construct an argument about `mod` or something leaving `0` or `1` in `eax` accordingly, but it's very brittle at best

Comment: @StoryTeller I guess he's looking at something like [this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f56ab30ee2d8a761). Pretty amusing, UB notwithstanding.

Comment: the function is equivalent to `int is_odd(int i) {}` how can you check that this gives "correct results" ?? This is just undefined behaviour

Comment: Assuming you had the proper `return`, how could `i % 2` be simultaneously 1 and -1?

Comment: @StoryTeller to check whether it is correct or not, i implemented my own function to check if its odd or not (one i can explain why it is correct). and they gave matching results.

Comment: @FredLarson yup i asked the same question^^ it also does not work if you change the if statement.

Comment: @DonMushroom, you are missing the point. That function doesn't have a well defined behavior. It's pointless to wonder why it's correct. And like **krzaq** said, it probably is due to machine code leaving junk in a register  that is meant to return the functions result

Comment: Not returning anything from a non-void function is UB per standard, thus any discussion about the results of running this code is pretty meaningless.

Comment: See what happens when the [calling convention of the function changes](http://ideone.com/lcfc0g)(Same compiler as before). Now it is the callee that must clean up the call stack, and result magically becomes 0.

Comment: I think it is pretty interesting. Leaving `if(i)` or `if(i % 2 == 1)` yields always `i`. The question is not about whether you should code like that but why it does so. The question is if the student knows about functions returning correct result even if they shouldn't

Comment: Your student deserves the lowest grade possible....

Comment: @brainsandwich thanks for understanding my point ;)

Comment: @SvenNilsson On the contrary, it looks like he should get a nice grade for using this trick

Comment: @brainsandwich only if he could explain it.

Comment: @krzaq It depends on grade ; and that piece of code could be part of an other assignment. It really looks like it was intended !

Comment: your student wants to confuse you or show off by writing incomprehensible code that may work on a specific compiler. he may be a hacker, but should not be rewarded for this.

Comment: @Sven Nilsson "wants to confuse you" - exactly. In  TartanLlama's sample to illustrate the "oddity" it simply happens to produce sequential zeros and ones only when -O0 is turned on. And he explained why this happens.

Comment: Personally, I would say the student gets points for knowledge of their compiler, but loses points for the code relying on UB (and thus potentially breaking at any given moment during any given compilation, potentially breaking if you switch to a different compiler, etc.), for a net result of 0.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flowing off the end of a function without returning anything is undefined behaviour, regardless of what actually happens with your compiler. Note that if you pass `-O3` to [GCC](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/ac52ac9cfc2538ca), or use [Clang](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a1d473cdf4318cda), then you get different results.

As for why you actually see the "correct" answer, this is the x86 assembly which GCC 6.2 produces at `-O0`:

```
    push    rbp
    mov     rbp, rsp
    mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
    cdq
    shr     edx, 31
    add     eax, edx
    and     eax, 1
    sub     eax, edx
    cmp     eax, 1
    nop
    pop     rbp
    ret
```

Don't worry if you can't read x86. The important thing to note is that `eax` is used for the return value, and all the intermediate calculations for the `if` statement use `eax` as their destination. So when the function exits, `eax` just happens to have the result of the branch check in it.

Of course, this is all a purely academic discussion; the student's code is wrong and I'd certainly give it zero marks, regardless of whether it passes whatever tests you run it through.

Comment: The brittleness of this can be further demonstrated by changing the calling convention, I think.

Comment: yeah the code might be wrong, but still I was wondering why it stillt works, because I want to understand why system behaves as it does. (as every good computer scientist should do ;))

Comment: Any reason for the downvote? Maybe I've angered someone by attempting to explain some UB :D

Comment: @DonMushroom a very good computer scientist should learn from a very good developer when they are advised to read the generated assembly.

Comment: @StoryTeller I never called my self a very good computer scientist ;) and as every open minded person I try to learn from every source possible :)

Comment: I mostly use MSVS and currently use MSVS2015 and this would yield either a compiler warning at least or a compiler error and won't even compile where older versions may still compile it with a warning. However aside from that and as StoryTeller mentioned about changing the calling convention within VS by default it is set to `__cdecl (/Gd)` option; try changing that to `__stdcall (/Gz)`, `__fastcall (/Gr)`, or `__vectorcall (/Gv)` and see what happens. There is no programming magic! This is UB and either it was sheer luck the student got this to work, or they are playing the system and you.